# Android google map that shows users locations

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

Is there any way that i can get the users location according to there phone number !!
or when they press a "check in" button or something !!
i have already write the GPS code for my current location

Comment: If you can get their phone number, you can probably get a region based off area code. If you mean their live pinpoint location, no.

Comment: but cant i get their latitude and longitude !! so i can store them in the  database and then use them ?

Comment: You can't with just a phone number, you'll need access to a location provider for more detailed positioning information. See [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html).